# Laravel relationships functions shows null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm creating a small webshop where users can create orders and sellers can see the orders. I have defined relationships but the related functions are null. This is how my tables looks like in phpmyAdmin https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPoHQ.jpg

This is how I have defined relationships in my models.

**User.php**

```
public function sellerOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
}
```

**Order.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity','total','Subtotal');
}

public function productInfo()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
 }

 public function orderInfo()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(OrderProduct::class, 'seller_id');
 }
```

This is my function in controller

```
$orders = Auth::user()->sellerOrders()->with('productInfo','orderInfo')->get();
```

When I `dd($orders)`, this is what i get

```
 Collection {#305 ▼
 #items: array:1 [▼
 0 => Order {#286 ▼
  #table: "orders"
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "user_id" => 1
    "shipping_email" => "878888"
    "shipping_name" => "hattta"
    "shipping_city" => "kljjdjd"
    "shipped" => 0
    "created_at" => "2019-07-05 01:33:58"
    "updated_at" => "2019-07-05 01:33:58"
  ]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "productInfo" => null
    "orderInfo" => null
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
]
}
```

How can I show `productInfo` and `orderInfo`?  Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: You are using `seller_id` as the foreign key in both `user()` and `orderInfo()`. And you haven't put the foreign key for `productInfo()`. Is it just `product_info_id`?

Comment: I did put `seller_id` in `productInfo()` and I got `null`. @newUserName02

Comment: `seller_id` should only be the foreign key for one of those, I'm guessing it's the user. You need to fill in the proper foreign keys for the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the attributes on the **Order** model from your dump, there is no field `seller_id`:

```
#attributes: array:8 [▼
"id" => 9
"user_id" => 1                      <--- There is a user_id, but not seller_id
"shipping_email" => "878888"
"shipping_name" => "hattta"
"shipping_city" => "kljjdjd"
"shipped" => 0
"created_at" => "2019-07-05 01:33:58"
"updated_at" => "2019-07-05 01:33:58"
]
```

You need to either add a `seller_id` field to the model and add the value to the database, or, perhaps easier, change your relations on the **Order** model so that the foreign key is `user_id` instead of `seller_id`.

Once you fix this, you should see a value for your `**user**` on the Order.  So if you loop through `$orders`, you can do $order->user and it should return the user for the order.

Same thing for your productInfo.  There is no `product_id` on the **Order** model, and because of the non-conventional name (i.e. it's not just '`product()`'), you will need to specify the foreign key in the relationship method on the **Order** model.  Also, don't forget to add the `product_id` to the **Order** model as fillable.

Same problem applies to your `orderInfo()` method - there is no `seller_id` on the order model to provide the relationship - same fix could apply as above.

Comment: I tried to add `seller_id` in the `Order` and what happens is when a user buys multiple products from different sellers at once , the order goes to one seller( which means that seller receives an order with products which some of them are not his products @Watercayman

Comment: I understand.  This is a different question though - you asked why the relationships were null, and I have answered that above.  What you are asking in terms of the mixing of orders to sellers is a different question that probably involves some re-thinking and re-architecting of your code.  I suggest you solve the original question first (get the relationships working and figure out how that all works using the FKs as noted), and then consider re-writing your code to solve the second issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because You have in relation return `hasMany` => in orders you will have an array and since you queried it already, you have to query each item like so:

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    echo $order->productInfo->propertyOfProductInforTable;
    echo $order->products->name; //or whatever is in your product table relation
}
```

Comment: how do I query as a relation? @Sarghei

Comment: @user11710915 you have to make sure that in your model you difine your relation public function like so: `public function phone() {return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');}` and then you can query a property of related table.